# How to write a large function to sort read from a dynamic array where the row is dynamic?

Tags: sorting, indexing, dynamic, excel-formula, dynamic-arrays

I have an array of elements say from A1:D(X). X can be calculated but is dynamic, so the array can be from A1:D20 or from A1:D100 or A1:D8. But 20, 100 or 8 can be calculated at the time of generation of array. I am using large function to sort elements of the array. How do I use the large function. (Large (A1:DX,1)). Value 8,20 or 100 is stored in E1.

Comment: What calculation is in E1? Does it calculate to the last row number of values in range D:D?

Comment: E1 is row number of last row in A:D.

Comment: As mentioned you could then use `=LARGE(A1:INDEX(D:D,E1),1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`=INDIRECT("A1:D"&E1)` will give you the range if I am understanding your question correctly. Then just `=LARGE(INDIRECT("A1:D"&E1),1)` will give you the largest value in that range.

As mentioned by P.b., another method that doesn't recalculate all the time is to use `INDEX` instead of `INDIRECT`

Comment: I understood it that way as well. Then `A1:INDEX(D:D,E1)` would be the same, but non-volatile

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic arrays in the `INDEX` function, and then use `SEQUENCE` with `E1` to access the part of the array that you need.

```
=LARGE(INDEX(A1#,SEQUENCE(1,E1),SEQUENCE(4)),1)
```

`A1#` is the array `A1:D10` in the example, and updates as required (hence dynamic!).

The first sequencer runs from row 1 to row `E1`, and the second runs through columns 1 to 4.

Then `LARGE` returns the maximum value in this subarray.

[image: indexed array]

(the data was created with `=SEQUENCE(10,4)` in `A1`).